# crontab -e stopped working for non-root user, /bin/sh: 1: mvim: not found, ubuntu 22.04

Tags: cron

The command `crontab -e` has stopped working under non-root user accounts and gives the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: mvim: not found
crontab: "mvim" exited with status 127
```

However, it still works for root with `sudo`. I don't know what has changed, just the regular `aptitude` upgrades.

Update:
I found this in my `.zshrc`. Commenting it out solved the problem.

```
# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
  export EDITOR='vim'
else
  export EDITOR='mvim'
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `crontab -e` will search the current environment for (in order) a `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` variable and attempt to use its value as the editor with which to open the crontab file.

So, you presumably set either `EDITOR=mvim` or `VISUAL=mvim` in your user's environment (perhaps you were intending to use the Neovim editor, `nvim`, but mistyped it?). You can check in bash with `declare -p VISUAL EDITOR`.

When run with `sudo` (unless you use the `-E` or `--preserve-env` switch), `crontab -e` is executed in a new, minimal environment that does not include the user's `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` variables.

You can override the setting temporarily on the command line e.g.

```
VISUAL=/bin/nano crontab -e
```

To fix the issue persistently, find where you are setting either of these variables (possibly your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file) and either set them to a valid editor program, or unset them - which will cause `crontab -e` to fall back to the system's default `nano` editor.